# Integer class in javascript

Tags: javascript, processing

Whenever I try to use the value `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in Javascript mode of Processing, I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError saying "Integer is not defined.

Can someone please explain this problem to me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

Java and javascript is not the same.

Javascript does not have Integer as a datatype

Comment: Not looking for type, but class/object.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), not `Integer`, there is no `Integer` class in javascript.

See [Number's MAX_VALUE property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE):

```
Number.MAX_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use Processing in Java mode, you can use the [Processing API](https://www.processing.org/reference/) as well as anything in the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). The Java API includes the [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class.

When you use Processing in JavaScript mode, you can use the [Processing.js API](http://processingjs.org/reference/) (which has a lot in common with the regular Processing API) as well as anything in the [JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).

**You can't use stuff from the Java API in JavaScript mode.** You have to look for alternatives in the JavaScript API.

A quick google search turns up the value of [Infinity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity), which you might try. You could also try [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/POSITIVE_INFINITY).

Also note that you can't use stuff from JavaScript in Java mode.